# Database modeling in MySQL Workbench for order system

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to model a simple order system in MySQL Workbench and i'm having a few problems when it comes to normalization. Right now, i'm using WHERE id = x, another_id = x and so on to build a query. My system is rather simple:

- User table
- Order table
- UserOrder table
- Product table

An user has many orders and an order has many products. And that's about it. How can one define such relations in the MySQL workbench? Are there any tutorials on HasMany, HasOne and other kinds of relationships?

[image]

Comment: Rather than `UserOrder` table, you would be better to store a FK to the relevant user within the `Order` table itself; an association table like `UserOrder` is only necessary for many-to-many relationships, such as you will need between `Order` and `Product` - therefore you will want an `OrderProducts` table.

Comment: But the user can make many orders.

Comment: Indeed.  And their FK can appear many times in the `Order` table (provided that you don't go and define a uniqueness constraint over the FK).

Comment: http://oi44.tinypic.com/iba0j4.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part your setup is okay.  However, you don't need mapping tables for one-to-many mappings.  For instance, it's highly unlikely that a single order can belong to multiple users and that an order item can belong to multiple orders.  This means that your tables should be:

- Users (userid)
- Orders (orderid, userid)
- OrdersItems (oiid, orderid, productid)
- Products (productid)

Comment: Is there a better way of INSERTing into the tables? For example: I have to insert into order, and then insert into order items.

Comment: @vinnylinux use a transaction